# Problems with cin

Tags: c++, cin, istream

I'm using cin in 2 different ways: one way I'm just using cin (overloaded)>> variable, and the other way I'm using a function called read, which takes in an istream.

The code I have for it is:

```
cin >> string6;
cout << string6; 
string7.read(cin); 
cout << string7;
```

The problem I think I'm having having is that whatever's left in cin from string6 is being used for string7 (if I read in "Hello" and followed by ^D^D to signify the end of input, I'm pretty sure ^D is being read into string7), so I can't read user input with string7.read(). How do I fix this problem?

EDIT: string6/string7 are variables of my String() class, and read is a member function of String.

Comment: Maybe you need [`std::getline()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/) instead of `string7.read()` ?

Comment: Can't do that, I must use read().

Comment: read() is not a member of std::string, what string are you using?

Comment: Well, do you understand that `std::string` doesn't have a standard `read()` method?

Comment: I'm using my String class, which is a linked list representation of a string. read() is a member function I have for it. All it does is ifstream >> *this.

Comment: @Jonathan Chiou Please show your code of class `String`

Comment: I just need to reset cin so I can read user input again. If I comment out any one of the statements, the other will work, my String class code isn't really needed.

Comment: @JonathanChiou What does `read` do internally? What function does it call?

Answer (score 0):

I dont have your code so i cant test it but this might work:

```
istream&  ignore ( streamsize n = 1, int delim = EOF );
```

Extracts characters from the input sequence and discards them.

```
cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

Answer (score 0):

"cin >>" will read up until the next newline character.  You can use cin.ignore() to remove characters.  You can also use cin.peek() to check what is currently at the front of the stream.

So,

```
if( cin.peek() == '^D' )
{
    cin.ignore();
}
```

Replacing '^D' with the actual code.  You could also just do something like

```
while( !isalpha( cin.peek() ) )
{
    cin.ignore();
}
```

to ensure that cin starts on an alpha character.